# In my Azure example solution AspProviders the project StorageClient is unavailable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, azure

I am having trouble loading Azure example solution AspProviders the StorageClient project is unavailable. What am I missing? What can should I check for?

(This example is found in the Azure SDK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StorageClient is another sample in the SDK.  Try running buildall.cmd from the root of the samples directory.

Comment: I got version 1.2 of the SDK and it isn't here. I ran `buildall`, but I'm not sure what it was supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the storage prior to running the sample? There should be an explanation of how to do this in the documentation.

whether run locally on in the cloud, the creation of storage is a separate step from deploying the cloud application.

Hope this makes sense.